# How to compute the genus of the (singular) intersection of three quadratics in $\mathbb{C}P^4$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, complete-intersection

Consider three quadratics in $\mathbb{C}P^4$:
$$
x_0^2+4x_1^2+\frac{x^2_2}{4}=0,~ x_1x_4+x_2x_3=0, ~ x_0^2+x_3^2+x_4^2=0.
$$

If there intersection *was* non-singular, then the intersection should be a curve of genus $5$, see [this note](https://chenhi.github.io/math6670-f19/solutions/hw10-4.pdf).

However, the intersection in our problem has $4$ singular points
$$
[0,\frac{1}{2},\pm 2i,0,0] \text{ and } [0,0,0, 1, \pm i].
$$

So it seems to me that (the normalization of) the intersection curve should have genus
$$
g=5-4=1.
$$

I want to know if my guess is correct and if it is part of some general result.

Comment: The curve is not indecomposable, so what do you mean by its genus?

Comment: @Sasha Yes the only possibilities are $x_1=\pm x_3$ and $x_2=\mp x_4$ so there are two components. I made some changes on the problem.

Comment: Not two, but four!

Comment: This is a valid deduction if the curve is irreducible and the singularities are all nodes. Can you check this?

Comment: @WillSawin "This is a valid deduction if the curve is irreducible and the singularities are all nodes." Do you know where I can find this result?

Comment: I believe Hartshorne contains (1) how to compute the arithmetic genus of a complete intersection, (2) resolving a node singularity reduces the arithmetic genus by 1, (3) for a smooth irreducible curve the arithmetic genus matches the geometric genus.